# PhpStorm not stopping at a breakpoint (xdebug)

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I've setup xdebug in my vagrant environment. [Another xdebug client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug/nhodjblplijafdpjjfhhanfmchplpfgl) can receive connections and it `breaks at first line`. The settings for this client are as follows:

[image]

I setup PhpStorm with similar settings but nothing happens when I `start listening for PHP Debug Connections`:

[image]
[image]

Also, in `Run` menu, `Break at first line in PHP scripts` is enabled.

Any help diagnosing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Set virtual path as content root of the project in File-Settings-Directories. See some useful information at [Debugging in PHPStrome] (http://blogs.jetbrains.com/webide/2011/03/configure-php-debugging-in-phpstorm-2-0)

Comment: Update: Thanks @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd. Even though that article is old, that setting stood out and helped solve my problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning off `Ignore external connections through unregistered server configurations` did the trick and it now works!

[image]